# How to find distinct folders which contains songs in Android Q using Mediastore, since MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA is deprecated

Tags: android, mediastore, android-10.0

How to find distinct folders which contains songs in Android Q using Mediastore, since MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA is deprecated

the old code which was used was

```
    public ArrayList<Song> FolderFilesList(Context context, String FolderPath) {
          //folder-exclude-sub-folders

            ArrayList<Song> songs = new ArrayList<>();

String[] columns = {
                MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,

        };


            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE ? AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " NOT LIKE ? ";
            String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    "%" + FolderPath + "%",
                    "%" + FolderPath + "/%/%"
            };

            Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    columns(), selection, selectionArgs, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Song song = new Song(
                            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)),
                            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)),
                            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID)),
                            cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)),
                            cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK)),
                            cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
                    );

                    //File f = new File(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)));
                    // if (f.isFile() && f.exists()) {
                    songs.add(song);
                    //}
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return songs;
        }
```

since `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA` is deprecated in Android Q how can we find distinct folder using `Mediastore`

Can we use URI for finding distinct folders of music files

Comment: You might be able to query for `RELATIVE_PATH` -- I do not know if I have tried retrieving that value.

Comment: I would use ALBUM and not use both LIKE ? and NOT LIKE ? while testing.

Comment: @commonsWare can you provide an Example , and from what i have read, the relative path has to be present in mediastore, (do all files have a mediastore entry for `RELATIVE_PATH` ) how do we find files if they dont have a RELATIVE_PATH

Comment: like commonsWare wrote: use `RELATIVE_PATH` instead of `DATA` in your selection. Use `Uri mageUri=ContentUris.wihAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)));` to get the uri of mediafiles. Further work with `Uri` instead of paths